# hibernate how to update cross-reference table

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I have a Patient table, Visit table and Doctor table.

Patient 1 ---- * Visit (Patient to Visit is one to many)

Visit 1 ---- * Doctor (Visit to Doctor is one to many)

My domain code was reverse engineering from existing database:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient")
    public Set<Visit> getVisits()
    {
        return this.visits;
    }

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "visit")
    public Set<Doctor> getDoctors()
    {
        return this.doctors;
    }
```

In my unit test code, I create a Patient without any Visit and save it into database. Close the session.

Then I start a new session to load the Patient back, I create a Visit and a Doctor. I add the Doctor to the Visit and add the Visit to the Patient. Then I call session.saveOrUpdate() to update the Patient. I committed the transaction and closed the session after the saveOrUpdate() call.

But I cannot find the Visit and Doctor data in the database tables.

My question are how can I save/update the Patient with its Visit and Doctor information?

Do I have to save the Visit and Doctor data separately before I update the Patient with them?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if cascaleAll works for you?
For example:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: how to make reverse engineering code has the CascadeType.All annotation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, most java projects archetypes nowadays with unit-testing are configured to **rollback any change**, so you wouldn't see any change in the physical table - check if that is the case in your project.

If not - you can try to manually create and save `Patient` and`Doctor` objects and flush the session (not commit).

With the session flushed, try to create the `Visit` object and commit.